# get document variables from ff extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, document

I have a ff extension that want to access a property in my current opening page.
 Here's js code in my loaded page, myVariable get created when web page is loaded:

```
document.myVariable = 3;
```

Here's my js code for my extension

```
var myVar = gBrowser.contentDocument.myVariable;
alert(myVar);
```

However, myVariable always return value "undefined". 
the extensions will be called when I press a button in a Toolbar menu, so I can make sure I press the button AFTER the web page is loaded. But still, it seems that it can't get the variable I created. Can anyone give me a hand ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can extension access global variables in other pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047201/how-can-extension-access-global-variables-in-other-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing it through gBrowser just use content.document.myVariable. That should work. Note that objects on your page are wrapped to limit what extension code can do with them.

Comment: hmm. it still give me same result. I think content.document is same as gBrowser.cotentDocument, is not it ?