# How can extension access global variables in other pages

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

There is a web page which contains the following parts:

```
<script language="javascript">
var g_GlobalVar1 = "Global Variable 1";
</script>
```

So how the variable `g_GlobalVar1` can be accessed by the `DOMContentLoaded` handler function of the Firefox extension script?

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, privileged code doesn't access web pages directly but through [XPCNativeWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper). This means in particular that you normally cannot read out any JavaScript properties that the web page added. You can [bypass the security layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper#Accessing_unsafe_properties) and access the variable as `wnd.wrappedJSObject.g_GlobalVar1` but this isn't recommended and you should consider using an alternative approach (which one depends on what you are trying to do with this web page).

Comment: Thanks. And I got a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103501/accessing-documents-javascript-variable-from-firefox-extension, which